# Perguntas sobre "Google Forms" podem ser feitas no site?

Tags: suporte, perguntas

Tenho uma pergunta que está a ter cotação negativa (recebendo downvote), a pergunta é sobre o [GoogleForms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/), e estou com dificuldade nesse campo.

- **Pergunta:** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124689/altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-tamanho-do-formul%C3%A1rio-do-google-forms

Existe algum tipo de site especifico para se fazer a pergunta ou posso fazer no *Stack Overflow em português*?

Comment: SoeiroMass não fui eu quem negativou, mas preciso dizer que mal entendo o que escreve, sitio que dizer site? É um termo bem incomum. Ok, o Stackoverflow portugues é um site e não possui mais sites. A [rede Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) é quem possui sites de diversos assuntos, até sobre religião e café, mas todos em inglês, o unico que tem variantes de idiomas são os stackoverflows. Eu não entendo nada de GoogleForms (é html?), mas me parece on-topic, recomendo que poste o link da pergunta aqui pra analisarmos, duvido muito que o motivo do negativo seja por offtopic.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento [Alteração do Tamanho do Formulário do Google Forms](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124689/altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-tamanho-do-formul%C3%A1rio-do-google-forms)

Comment: Realmente não percebo o motivo do -1, a pergunta a mim parece-me boa embora eu não perceba nada de Google forms.

Comment: Obrigado pela participação de todos, de facto a pergunta não estáva super perceptiva, mas dava minimamente para perceber.

Comment: @SoeiroMass de nada, realmente não entendo o porquê do -1 nesta pergunta nem na que fizeste do Google forms.

Comment: Eu acho que a confusão estava no facto de estar a utilizar a palavra 'pergunta' para duas situações, eu referia-me à Pergunta no StackOverflow Português e estava também a falar da Pergunta que tinha no GoogleForms e acho que o pessoal misturou  as duas palavras e a pergunta acabou por ficar confusa para algumas pessoas.

Espero que já esteja mais perceptivel e que quem souber me possa ajudar. Obrigado.

Comment: @SoeiroMass acho melhor evitar de escrever tão formalmente, isto torna a leitura cansativa e as vezes confusa pra maioria, desculpe não quero lhe ofender, mas as vezes nem esta parecendo formal mas sim exagerado na maneira que escreve usando palavras tão incomuns ao cotidiano que acaba deixando as pessoas sem entender o que realmente quer dizer, eu pelo menos tive dificuldade de entender o que escreveu. Independente de português brasileiro ou europeu. Posso estar enganado, mas esse pode ser o motivo de não entenderem o seu problema.

Comment: @SoeiroMass um adicional, a sua pergunta só teve um downvote, isso não quer dizer nada, pode ser uma opinião de alguém que discorda do tipo de pergunta ou da maneira que escreveu, mas em base a pergunta parece atender aos requisitos mínimos da comunidade. Uma dica, recomendo que faça uma cópia do seu form e essa compartilhe na sua pergunta o link do form. Eu tentei criar um googleform ontem mas não me apareceu o tal espaçamento.

Comment: Obrigado pela opinião, vou tentar corrigir para as próximas perguntas que faça, vou tentar escrever de uma forma mais tranquila.
Mais uma vez obrigado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Na minha opinião*, por mais que a sua pergunta esteja bastante clara e não mereça negativação, eu entendo que ela não faz parte do escopo do site. A pergunta não tem nenhuma relação direta com programação, pois trata apenas da configuração de um produto de software (o Google Forms).

Se perguntas de configuração desse tipo fossem aceitas, por consistência nós deveríamos aceitar também dúvidas sobre como configurar o Blogger, como configurar o feed do Twitter, ou mesmo sobre como alterar os critérios de segurança do perfil do Facebook.

Acho que seria o caso de ela fazer parte do escopo se envolvesse alguma necessidade relacionada com programação, como por exemplo alguma alteração de comportamento via código (é possível programar certas coisas no Google Drive - [vide exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/238/73)), ou mesmo algum uso tangencial em um sistema qualquer em desenvolvimento.

Reitero que *eu* não acho que esse seja um motivo válido para negativação. Mas, sabe como é: em uma comunidade grande como a nossa, as pessoas têm opiniões diferentes e todo mundo tem direito a votar como quiser. Talvez quem negativou a sua questão julgou que ela mereceria o voto negativo por não ter relação com o escopo do site. Ou talvez não seja esse o motivo. Enfim, é impossível ter certeza se quem negativou optou por não deixar um comentário.

Comment: Desde já agradeço pela resposta, eu lembrei-me que podia não ter muito haver com programação, lembrei me disso ainda antes de colocar a pergunta, mas como reparei que existia a tag form, e no stackoverflow internacional havia a tag google-forms eu pensei que não havia problema, e caso alguém soubesse como aceder ao html das paginas de google forms, eu a partir de ai sabia o que fazer ao editar a pagina por html, porque pelo que vi na net, antigamente dava para ter acesso ao Source Code, mas agora já não dá ou não sei onde é.

Obrigado por todos os esclarecimentos.

Comment: Por nada. :) Eu realmente não sei como fazer o que vc quer, senão ajudava aqui. Mas, nada te impede de perguntar no [chat], por exemplo. :)